# how to get values from db and insert them to events array

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, fullcalendar

My code is as below.

```
<script>
    var t=<?php echo json_encode($ta)?>;
    var d=<?php echo json_encode($da)?>;

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            //defaultDate: '2016-03-12',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events

            //$r=$ev->title;

            for(var j=0;j<d.length;j++)
            {
                events: [{
                        title: t[j],
                        start: d[j]
                    }
                ]

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have used the fullcalendar 2.6.1. But nothing displayed. Please can anybody help me? I want to retrieve all the title and eventDate from the db and view in the calendar. The var t and d contains the all the data of $ta and $da arrays. I just wanted to assign them to events array title and start keywords.There are some red marks indicate that for loop is going to be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
<?php 
    $ta=array();
    $i=0;
?>
@foreach($events as $ev)
    <?php
        $ta[$i]['title'] = $ev->title;
        $ta[$i]['start'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($ev->eventDate));
        $i++;
    ?>

@endforeach

<script>
    var t=<?php echo json_encode($ta)?>;

    $(document).ready(function() {


        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            //defaultDate: '2016-03-12',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: t,
            eventRender: function(event, element) {
                $('.fc-time', element).hide();
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. That will be displayed inside the right cage of the calendar. But there's some garbage value displayed near the title as 12a. Why is that?

Comment: I updated answer and added eventRender function to hide 12a.

Comment: That is worked perfectly. Thank you very much. How do you know about it?

Comment: I am using fullcalnedar since 3 years :)  Please accept answer by right tick mark and up vote to answer if you got help from this answer. So that other can get help throught your question and my answer.

Comment: Please can you help me to figure out how to change the css of event calendar for adding a background color/image for the added event dates?

Comment: You can give class name as event property and set your css with given name in your css file. This will automatically set class to your event. Like $ta[$i]['clasName'] = 'yourClassName';

Comment: Thank u. That works fine. But $ta[$i]['clasName'] should be                    $ta[$i]['className']

Comment: Do you know how to set different colors to different colors for different events?

Comment: You can set color property for event. Like  $ta[$i]['color'] = '##393318'

Comment: Thank you. ##393318 is displayed the default color similar to blue. Never mind, I think I need to pass the color through a variable to change accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     $.ajax({
>               url:'',
>               dataType: 'json',
>
>               success: function(doc) {
>                   var events = [];
>               $.each(doc, function(key, value){
>                           events.push({
>                               title : value['title name'],
>                               start : value['hours'],
>                               backgroundColor: Metronic.getBrandColor('yellow'),
>
>                               id : value['id']
>                           });
>                       });
>                   AddFullCalenderEvent(events);
>               }
>           });
>
> function AddFullCalenderEvent(eventList){
>       $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
>           events: eventList,
>
>           eventClick: function(event) {
>               // opens events in a popup window
>
>               window.location.href = "pagename?id=" + event.id;
>
>               return false;
>           }
> ```

Try this